# If $\nu$ is a complex measure, then $L^1(\nu) = L^1(|\nu|)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove the following statement from Folland: If $\nu$ is a complex measure, then $L^1(\nu) = L^1(|\nu|)$ and if $f \in L^1(\nu)$, then $\left| \int f \; d \nu \right| \leq \int |f| \; d |\nu|$.

I was able to prove the latter statement.  Folland proves earlier that $\left| \dfrac{d \nu}{d |\nu|} \right| = 1$, $|\nu|$-a.e., so using a previous proposition regarding positive measures, $$\left| \int f \; d \nu \right| = \left| \int f \dfrac{d \nu}{d |\nu|} \; d |\nu| \right| \leq \int |f| \left| \dfrac{d \nu}{d |\nu|} \right| \; d |\nu| = \int |f| \; d |\nu|.$$

To show that $L^1(|\nu|) \subseteq L^1(\nu)$, then I think I can just use the inequality above, replacing $f$ with $|f|$.  Will this work?

It is when I try to show that $L^1(\nu) \subseteq L^1(|\nu|)$ that I get really tripped up.  I know that if $f \in L^1(\nu)$, then $f \in L^1(\nu_r^+),L^1(\nu_r^-),L^1(\nu_i^+),L^1(\nu_i^-)$, where $\nu_r^+,\nu_r^-,\nu_i^+,\nu_i^-$ denote the positive and negative variations of the real and imaginary parts of $\nu$.  I also know that there is some function $g$ with $d \nu = g \; d \mu$, where $\mu = |\nu_r|+|\nu_i|$ by the Radon-Nikodym Theorem, and so $d |\nu| = |g| \; d \mu$.  I've tried to get a string of inequalities by attempting to "break up" $\int |f| \; d \nu$ and "put it back together" in terms of $\mu$, but I'm just not getting anywhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

See [(complex measures) $d\nu=d\lambda +f\,dm \Rightarrow d|\nu|=d|\lambda| +|f|\,dm$ and $f\in L^1(\nu)\Rightarrow f\in L^1(|\nu|)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1087154/16418) for a similar question.

It is easy to prove this when $\nu$ is a real-valued measure. In the complex measure case, we may write $\nu=\nu_r+i\,\nu_i$, where $\nu_r$ and $\nu_i$ are real-valued measures. Define $\mu=|\nu_r|+|\nu_i|$. Then $d\nu_r=h\,d\mu$ and $d\nu_i=k\,d\mu$ for some real-valued functions $h,k\in L^1(\mu)$. We also have $\nu\ll\mu$. So $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=h+i\,k$. Let $g=h+i\,k$. Let's use $L^1(d\nu)$ to denote $L^1(\nu)$. Then $$L^1(d\nu)=L^1(h\,d\mu)\cap L^1(k\,d\mu)=L^1(|h|\,d\mu)\cap L^1(|k|\,d\mu)=L^1(|g|d\mu)=L^1(d|\nu|)$$ 
The first and the last equalities are just definitions. The second equality is the real measure case, and the third one is a result of the trivial inequality $\max\{|h|, |k|\}\le|g|\le|h|+|k|$.