# What is $|v|$ for complex measure $|v|$?

Tags: real-analysis

In Real analysis from Folland, we define $|v|$ when $v << u$ for some positive measure $u$, $dv = f du$ for some $f$ in $L^1$, $d|v| = |f|du$.
But in page 99, folland's book, the proof of thm 3.22 says that "IT IS EASILY VERIFIED THAT $d|v| = d|p| + |f|dm"$. Hmm... I can't find definition of $d|v|$ when $dv = dp + fdm$. What is this?

Comment: Any book on complex measuers surely defines $|\mu|$ for a complex measure $\mu$ You should find it yourself in the book.

Comment: I did not read Folland, but in Rudin the notation $|v|$ is used for the total variation of a measure.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087154/complex-measures-d-nu-d-lambda-f-dm-rightarrow-d-nu-d-lambda-f-dm?rq=1